# Offline Automatic Speech Recognition(ASR) In Android with maximum accuracy

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, tensorflow-lite, cmusphinx

I am looking for ASR in android with maximum accuracy and went through some implementations as follows

1. Android Recognizer(Native Android)
2. Sphinx
3. Tensor flow lite
4. KeenASR
5. kitt.ai

Need some inputs about which one to use because for Android Recognizer when I tried offline the accuracy decreased. Is there anyone who has used any of them and working offline with maximum accuracy in speech recognition in terms of different voices, voice modulation, background noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found keen ASR with good offline support